# Is there a way to populate a column based on distinct from two?

Tags: excel, oracle, pivot

I am trying to achieve something like this in oracle. I know there is a function in excel like *=IF(SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A2=A2)*($B$2:$B2=B2))>1,0,1)* which can populate a column based on distinct combination of 2. It is possible to do so in oracle as well? The reason is, in excel, I have around 110K records with string so it is very slow operation to populate a column using this formula as pivot again re-calculates it.

Further, when we export the data to excel, we can use pivot > sum of those 3 rd column to see the count of distinct, group by column 1.

[image: confused]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use simple `ROW_NUMBER` analytic function:

```
WITH data (class, name) AS (
    SELECT 'Class1', 'James' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Class1', 'Sara' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Class1', 'Alan' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Class1', 'Sara' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Class2', 'Cheryl' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Class2', 'Cheryl' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Class2', 'Cheryl' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Class3', 'Alice' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Class3', 'Flora' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Class3', 'Franklin' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Class3', 'Nicol' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Class3', 'Franklin' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Class4', 'Bess' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Class4', 'Lucy' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Class4', 'William' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Class4', 'Bess' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Class4', 'Lucy' FROM DUAL
)
SELECT
    data.*,
    CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY class, name ORDER BY ROWNUM) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END helper
FROM
    data
ORDER BY
    ROWNUM
```